# Error in Magento log Zend_XmlRpc_Client_HttpException with message "Not Allowed" Resulting in blank content section in admin

Tags: php, magento

this is my first time asking a question on SO. So please be understanding if this may not be worded in the best way feedback appreciated!

First, the error message in the exception.log file of Magento:

> 2016-01-12T00:16:22+00:00 ERR (3): 
>   exception 'Zend_XmlRpc_Client_HttpException' with message 'Not Allowed' in C:\wamp\www\local.powercrunch.com\store\lib\Zend\XmlRpc\Client.php:294

Second my problem in more detail:
I am unable to access the content that was created by the module creator. my admin page is displaying the container with header and footer, but blank content section. I have the config.xml, adminhtml.xml, module_name.xml files configured along with the controller and block files. I understand this is not a lot of info, however I can't figure out how to post code to this question or attach my code files. If I paste the code here is does not display correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Marc - off the bat, your second problem sounds like a symptom of a missing layout file. Check your adminhtml.xml file to see what the layout name it defines it, then check that it exists in `app/design/adminhtml/...`

Comment: Hi Robbie. I thought of that, and I revised my layout file (I created one) to match the path described in a book I found: Magento Made Easy. I found it in the google store (free). Is there a way to attach a file to this question? I can include my existing layout file and see if you see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out on my own. I found out that my config.xml file was missing the `<layout>` declaration to link it to my layout file. for those reading this question, the lesson I learned is to double check your config.xml file before looking elsewhere. If I had done that, I would have saved myself days of searching.